# What is the cause of java.lang.NullPointerException in my spring boot mockMVC test case?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockmvc

**MyCode**

```
 @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    public class NewsletterTest {

      @Autowired
      private MockMvc mockMvc;


      @MockBean
      private NewsletterService service;

      @Test
      public void deleteNewsletterShouldDelete() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .delete("/delete-newsletter/11")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(service, times(1)).deleteNewsletter(11L);

    }
```

**The error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.NewsletterTest.deleteNewsletterShouldDelete(NewsletterTest.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
```

In my spring boot test case, I am using @AutoConfigureMockMvc and @MockBean to test a delete method in my newsletter controller. However, I am encountering a java.lang.NullPointerException at line 33 of my test case. I want to understand the cause of this error.

Comment: Hello! This is quite hard to know what your issue might be as we don't have the line number. But I guess the line with `this.mockMvc.perform` throws the NPE?

Comment: Yes, Line 33 is  this.mockMvc.perform, it throws the NPE because mockMvc is null but i don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your only anontation on your test is `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. However that is not sufficient to start a Spring Boot application context.

As you are targeting a controller you should at least add `@WebMvcTest(controllers=[controller_class_here]`.

This will setup everything and maybe resolve your NullPointerException.

Also doing so you won't need the `@AutoconfigureMockMvc` annotation

Comment: @Mark likes Quark do not hesitate to mark as accepted answers if it unblocked you! :)

Comment: Yeah i tried it like this:
  @WebMvcTest(controllers=NewsletterController.class)
But it still gives me the exact same NPE

Comment: Do you use the correct import for the `@Test` annotation? Importing `junit.test` instead of `junit;jupiter.api.Test` can also cause this kind of issue

Comment: The Test just gets ignored now and the  junit.test import is not working for me